# 419 expired page after using middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

i added a simple middleware to my project after that i got 419 page! i use laravel 6

rout page :

```
Route::post('cours','AdminController@coursSubmit')->middleware('chekname');
```

view page:

```
<form action="edusubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="title">
                                <br><hr>
                                <input name="publisher" type="text"value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" readonly>
                                <br><hr>
                                <textarea name="description" placeholder="در این قسمت متن مقاله ی خود را وارد کنید"></textarea>
                                <br><hr>
                                <label>عکس مقاله را بارگزاری کنید</label>
                                <br>
                                <input name="image" type="file">
                                <br><hr>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit">
                                <br><hr>
                            </form>
```

middleware:

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->title == 'masoud')
        return $next($request);
        return view('/');
    }
}
```

kernel:

```
'chekname' => chekName::class,
```

Comment: please include ur middleware code as well

Comment: the codes attached to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify kernel

```php
 'chekname' => \App\Http\Middleware\chekName::class,
```

modify middleware

```php
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->title != 'masoud'){
             return redirect('/');
          }
        return $next($request);
    } 
}
```

in middleware u should return `$next($request);`

Comment: after doing your solution i got this error !!

"Call to a member function setCookie() on null"

Comment: where you are settling cookie check

Comment: i didn't , actually i'm new in laravel

Comment: I solved the problem, I used 'view' instead of 'redirect' in the condition